# Move the eval $(pyenv init -) from zsh to xonsh

Tags: zsh, pyenv, xonsh

How can I move `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` that is in `.zshrc` to `.xonshrc`?
What is the syntax in `xonsh` to do that?

Comment: you should post some context, eg add a snippet of your .bashrc containing  the line.  

This appears to not be a ubiquitous setting.

Answer (score 1):

`pyenv` (at the moment) only supports POSIX compliant shells (like `bash` or `zsh`) as well as the `fish` shell. `pyenv` is not just a wrapper around `python`, it integrates itself into the running shell session in order to transparently provide the desired virtualenv.

```sh
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

takes the output of `pyenv init -` and runs (evaluates) it in the context of the running shell, just as if the output was written there instead of the `eval` command.

Having a look at the output of `pyenv init -` you can see, that it is a bit of shell code, that - among other things - defines the `pyenv` function.

```sh
export PATH="/home/adaephon/local/opt/pyenv/shims:${PATH}"
export PYENV_SHELL=zsh
source '/home/adaephon/local/opt/pyenv/libexec/../completions/pyenv.zsh'
command pyenv rehash 2>/dev/null
pyenv() {
  local command
  command="$1"
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    shift
  fi

  case "$command" in
  activate|deactivate|rehash|shell)
    eval "$(pyenv "sh-$command" "$@")";;
  *)
    command pyenv "$command" "$@";;
  esac
}
```

If run in a `fish` shell, `pyenv init -` returns code that does the same, but in `fish`'s syntax.

-

For `pyenv` to work with `xonsh` it would have to output `xonsh`-compatible variable and function definitions. As far as I can see, you would have to at least edit the files `libexec/pyenv-init` and `libexec/pyenv-sh-shell` (and probably some plugins) for that.

Comment: This is the correct answer, I think. Alternatively, xonsh vox plugin would need to implement the features of pyenv to enable installing and using alternative interpreters. As it is now, it creates a venv using the interpreter that it is itself running under (it's in dist-packages). I love xonsh and wish vox had this feature. As it is, if you just *must* switch between multiple python versions, a bash shell with pyenv is basically the only sane way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

`pyenv init -` generates a bit of bash code that can be sourced.  xonsh has a way to source bash code: `source-bash`.  Unfortunately, `source-bash` only takes a file as argument; it doesn't consume STDIN.  The solution is fairly simple, though:

```
pyenv init - > /tmp/pyenv
source-bash /tmp/pyenv > /dev/null
```

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the shell you run these commands in? If you run this - like the question asker -- in the fish shell the output is fish-, not bash-compatible, right?